# How to loop through timer class for delayed time?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, countdowntimer

I want run timer for about 30000 ms and up to 8 or more times each so here is my loop but it runs all timers at once after 30000ms

```
    public void repeatTimerTask() {
    repeat = 8; // need to run 30 sec timer for 8 times but one after one

    startTimer(30000); // firsat timer for 30 sec

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    for (int a = 1; a<=repeat; a++) {

        final int finalA = a;
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                startTimer(30000);

            }

        }, 30000); // delay until to finish first timer for 30 sec
    }
}
```

Comment: Your loop does not block and completes all iterations immediately so  all handler instances are created at once, thus seeming to run a once, you need to start a new timer task on completion of the previous - this logic should be in the task itself, or some way of signalling completion, possibly with a callback inside a custom `Runnable`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Mark Keen, yes what you said above is true but starting new timer is really hectic, because if user wants timer to run for about 32 times (on undefined number times) what do? or how to code for it?

Comment: The below answer is one of many possible solutions, which addresses the issue of starting a new task every 30 seconds.  However it has flaws, there is no way to cancel tasks, and the `Handler` instances can cause short term memory leaks because the `Runnable` instances have an implicit reference, which is held until processed, of the outer class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a timer for n seconds you can use [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer)

Declare two varibales globbaly. One for number of times you want to repeat. and one to keep the count of repetaion.

```
 private int NUM_REPEAT = 4;
 private int REPEAT_COUNT = 0;
```

Then call this method wherever you want. One thing to note if you want to run this loop 5 times you have to give number of repeation 4. Cause to satrt this function you have to call it so that will not come in count.

```
private void startTimer() {

    new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
        int secondsLeft = 0;

        public void onTick(long ms) {
            if (Math.round((float) ms / 1000.0f) != secondsLeft) {
                secondsLeft = Math.round((float) ms / 1000.0f);
                // resend_timer is a textview
                 resend_timer.setText("remaining time is "+secondsLeft);
                ;
            }
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            Log.d(TAG, "timer finished "+REPEAT_COUNT);
            if (REPEAT_COUNT <= NUM_REPEAT) {
                startTimer();
                REPEAT_COUNT++;
            }

        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code dear @Satyajit Das,  I want to repeat CountDownTimer for n number times as well as n number of seconds. and this code is just timer, thank you

Comment: @ThippeshS Updated the answer with loop. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Thanks for the update dear @Satyajit Das, and exactly I have implemented as per your updated answer with the help of Rahul Sonpaliya's answer, but without handler and your updated answer also fits well for my need, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code, and call 'startTimer' method where you first want to start your timer :

```
private int startTimerCount = 1, repeat = 8;

private void startTimer(){
    // if startTimerCount is less than 8 than the handle will be created
    if(startTimerCount <= repeat){
        // this will create a handler which invokes startTimer method after 30 seconds
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startTimer();
            }
        }, 30000);

        // do what you want
        Toast.makeText(this, "startTimer " + startTimerCount, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    startTimerCount++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code dear @Rahul Sonpaliya, it helps but not reliable, I just want to repeat (loop) timer for n number times as well as n number of seconds. and I am trying out with this, will updates once I done, thank you

Comment: thanks once again @Rahul Sonpaliya, without handler it works best just  `private int startTimerCount = 1, repeat = 8;` and `startTimerCount++;` did everything